# Cmd window unexpectedly closes

Tags: batch-file, math, time

I have a windows Bach program Im writing to log computer up time and down time.

Im kinda new to coding, but I have found how to do math time, even with dates here and at robvanderwoude.com.

There I found a batch file that, using the command line:

```
DateDiff [date1] [date2]
```

to get the days past but when I run it the program just shuts-down after the information is gathered.

How would I get the program to continue working?

```
    @Echo off
    FOR %%A in (%DATE%) DO SET Today=%%A
    ::test information
    Set lastdayran= 03/25/2015
    DateDiff %Today% %lastdayran%
    Pause
```

Comment: Show us your code. You're probably just reaching the natural end of the script, which closes if you run the script by double-clicking it.

Comment: I have the pause command at the end of my program. It shouldn't close.

Answer (score 1):

The script is closing because you aren't using `call` to run DateDiff.bat. When you run a script without using `call`, flow transfers to the second script and stays there. If you use `call`, script flow returns to the original script once the second script completes.

```
@Echo off
FOR %%A in (%DATE%) DO SET Today=%%A
::test information
Set lastdayran= 03/25/2015
Call DateDiff %Today% %lastdayran%
Pause
```

Comment: The DateDiff.bat is ran like a command, when I call it up the "syntax" of the command is given not the output.

Comment: @Echi - It's still a separate script. You call separate scripts with the `call` command. Trust me, I tried it myself and it pauses when you include the `call`. I promise.